# How to delegate all method calls to C# DLL in Python

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, python.net

I want to delegate all method call to C# DLL that we have written. I am using pythonnet to load the DLL file and call the methods from the DLL.

This is my python class and it works fine,

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('MyDll')
from MyDll import MyLibrary


class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = MyLibrary()

    def method1(self, first_arg, *args):
        self.lib.method1(first_arg, args)

    def method2(self, first_arg, *args):
        self.lib.method2(first_arg, args)
```

But I am not doing anything in python code except making a call to dll methods, so I don't want to write wrapper methods for all the methods in dll.

The above approach allows me to call python methods like, `MyProxy().method1(first_arg, arg2, arg3, arg4)`, which in turns passes the `first_arg` as the first argument and `arg2, arg3, arg4` as an array in the second argument to `self.lib.method1(first_arg, args)`.

This behavior is necessary for me because all of my C# methods have signature `method1(String first_arg, String[] other_args)`

How can I achieve this by only implementing `__getattr__` in my python class?

I have tried the below approach, but it throws error "No matching methods found",

```
class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = MyLibrary()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.lib, item)
```

**Edit:**
I think, when I wrap a DLL method like this,

```
def method1(self, first_arg, *args):
    self.lib.method1(first_arg, args)
```

python takes care of converting other arguments except the first one to an array and pass that array to DLL method. It matches the signature of DLL method(`method1(String first_arg, String[] other_args)`), since python passes the second argument as an array.

Can we do anything in `__getattr__` method to do the array conversion of other arguments except first one and pass on to DLL methods ?

Comment: Webservers usually run under very restrictive user accounts. Can the Webserver even see the dll in question? Or the required code from PythonNet?

Comment: This is a desktop application and it is run under admin account. First approach works fine, but I don't want to change my python code every time the .net guy adds a new method.

Comment: Is it definitely failing looking for one of the methods in your DLL? Maybe it's failing when looking some standard python methods. You could try raising `AttributeError` if `item not in ['method1', 'method2']`.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge No, it is able to find the method, but its not able find the matching signature based on how I call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this might work:

```
class MyProxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib = MyLibrary()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        lib_method = getattr(self.lib, item)
        def _wrapper(first_arg, *args):
            return lib_method(first_arg, args)
        return _wrapper
```